# How can I restart list item ID numbering at 1?

Tags: list, list-item

I deleted list items that include an ID from the list and the recycle bin. When I create a new list item, the ID populates where the last line item left off.

Now is there a way to make a new ID Column where the ID will always be reset to 1?
Cause i have to make a dashboard which lists all entries of a list and i don't know how I would do this else wise...

Comment: It might also help us if we knew what your requirements were. Why are you using list item IDs?

Comment: Nevermind, I see you posted a [follow-up question](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/13511/how-can-i-create-a-manual-id-in-sharepoint-lists-without-using-sharepoint-id).

Comment: Make of list template of your list save it without content and after creation of list template create same list from that template, item id will start from 1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Save the list as a template and recreate the list.  ID columns will always keep incrementing and will never be reused.