# How Can I create a manual ID in SharePoint Lists without using SharePoint ID?

Tags: list, sharepoint-designer

In my site I have two lists. These lists need to sync together. Since I can't create a list within a list, my only other option that I am aware of is to create two lists and sync them together by using an ID.

My first list allows a user to enter a project and needs an ID (the only way I can get the lists to sync?). The second list (Task List) will allow other users of a project to make comments and updates. I was advised when a user makes an update for example: to 'Comments', we want to keep the previous 'Comment' and still view the new 'Comment' in the list (a rollup list-this is why I thought using an ID would be a good idea).

How do I create a manual ID in SharePoint Lists without using a SharePoint ID (auto) to get this done? Is it possible to have more than one line item share the same ID number to sync or corelate to another list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can still use the internal ID columns for this.  Your parent (Project) list will use the basic internal ID column.  Your child list (Tasks) you'll create a lookup column to the Project List and utilize it's ID column.

When a task is created, it will ask what the associated projectid is and they'll be presented with a drop down list of all the IDs in the Project list.

If you wanted it manually maintained, you'd just create a ProjectID column in the project list and still use the same lookup method, but instead of pointing to the ID column, you'd point it to the ProjectID column.

Comment: I am not presented with an associated projectid, where do i find this?

Comment: You have to create a lookup column in the task list.  In the configuration of it, it will ask for the list and the column.  If those are set as desired and nothing appears in the drop down when you create a task, that means you haven't created any projects yet, so there is no project to select yet.

Comment: Ok, I have a column named Project ID as a 'Lookup'. Should I require this column to contain information? I have the 'Get Info From'pointing to the Parent List. In the 'In this column:' do I want ID? There is also, Modified, Created, Version, and Title. I didn't add these to the list, I believe they were already there.

Comment: Yes, you'd want to make it require information so that you can maintain the relationship.  If you want to utilize the Project lists internal ID column, point it to the ID column.  If you want your own maintainable ProjectID column, you'll need to create that in the Project list first, then use that in the task list lookup column.

Comment: Ok, I had done that and when I went to the site to add a new Project (Parent) I am given an ID6, then when I go to Action (Child) and create a new item then ID5 is created, but when I go to view or edit...it shows it's linked with ID6. Wouldn't that be confusing to an end user? Is it normal to have two columns (ProjectID; ProjectID:ID)? When I select the first ProjectID column, it shows that I can delete it, the other does not have that option.

Comment: Every list and library has an internal ID column, think of it like Access.  The ID column is the "primary key" for each list.  It can be a little confusing I guess, but so long as they're labeled appropriately it shouldn't be too  much of an issue.

Comment: Thank you PirateEric. :) - Now the Child retreives the number from the parent. But I did run into a snafu. I want the child to be able to retreive from the parent more than one time. When I tried using the same ProjectID twice, I was given an error indicating the number was already in use. I need to be able to allow multiple users to log into the child and work with the parent. I hope that makes sense, sorry if it doesn't. "This value already exists in the list. " And what I just found out is if I change the title, then everything is changed. I have to keep ALL comments I was advised.

Comment: You should be able to create as many child entries that reference the parent.  Is there something in the child lookup column that is making it allow unique values?

Comment: OK, I removed the 'Enforce Unique Values' and it is now allowing me to use the ID more than once. :).

Comment: Ok, I had to replicate this where it actually goes and WOW! When you have the strategy of what needs to be and how to do what you are looking to do, it does not take long. The last issue I ran into, on the test page and main site is this. Using the Parent, when I want to edit the webpage to display the titles, when I leave the page and go back to it, the titles are gone and I have to open the 'Edit WebPart' again to get this how we would like it to display. Is there a way I can force this to stay open? Thank You :)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean.

Comment: Can I send a screen shot? It would be best to explain it if I could send you something visual.

Comment: I'd rather not broadcast my email address about.  Can you upload it to a photosharing service?

Comment: Understandable. You know what? I think I just resolved the issue. Thank you though...thanks again for your help! :)

Comment: Great, that's what we're here for!

Comment: @PirateEric - I don't know if you will get this, but only hope so. I thought I was done with this project, but it appears there are other ideas. "I would like for it to be one site for each Project Charter (Parent). The project charter (Parent) home would have a list of all sub-sites; you would create a new Project Charter (Parent) from a site template. Each Project Charter site should have all the information about the project visible on the main page of the site. Something like this:" then there is an image of what they want it to look like.

Comment: ---To my knoweldge, the Project Charter is where a user will enter in a new project and there is an Action Plan (Child) that is used to allow all the members on the project to write what they had done for the project. Is what I am being asked possible? I'm thinking if I don't know the next project name, because I'm not in on the project, how am I to do this?

Comment: That might be something for another question.  It will also mean that instead of creating columns on the list level, you'll need to be creating site columns and/or content types in order to utilize Parent information in subsites.

Comment: So I basically have to scrap this and start from scratch? - great.

Comment: If the requirements are changing, then yes, based on what we had discussed, it will need to be rearchitected.  The principles are still the same, you're just doing it in another place is all.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than configuring your own ID and trying to sync the lists, it would be better to use a lookup column in your Task List to the Project List.

From your description, though it sounds like you want to allow the user to update a field in the Project list from the Task list. Instead, you could create the new Comment field on the task list and then create a DataView web part with a linked data source to join your lists together.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MiI-EJYTEp8

there are 6 videos. you will get to know how to create a parent child relationship. its awesome.
you can create new child item from parent list.